# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement, error python

Tags: python, ssl

I am trying to install `reverse_geocoder` module but I keep getting the following error

```
PS C:\Users\Raneem> pip install reverse_geocoder
pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Collecting reverse_geocoder
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/reverse-geocoder/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/reverse-geocoder/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/reverse-geocoder/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/reverse-geocoder/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/reverse-geocoder/
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/reverse-geocoder/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/reverse-geocoder/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement reverse_geocoder (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for reverse_geocoder
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org reverse_geocoder
```